# MS Windows and Firefox - OWA won't print

Tags: windows, outlook-web-access

I'm a small business user with offices in the UK and in France - ignoring how clunky OWA is it printed emails fine until recently when it ceased to print text when open in Firefox, my preferred browser, and only prints the header and footer - - apparently I don;t have a 50 reputation to comment on a previous post on this issue hence my raising it again.  Any solutions anyone?

Answer (score 0):

I believe at present this issue is still with Microsoft however it would appear to be Firefox related so how much Microsoft will do about is debatable.

My understanding is that the only workaround is to use Ctrl & P to print rather than the print drop down in Firefox, although not sure this prints a whole Email or just the one page you are on at the time.